# Not able to query custom k-table

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

### Trying to create a ktable to query it for data below using custom serdes.

```
  @Component
public class QueryingService {
    @Autowired
    public void buildKTableForQuerying(
            StreamsBuilder builder,
            MyCustomObjectSerde myCustomObjectSerde) {
        KStream<String, MyCustomObject> textLines = builder.stream("custom-input-topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.serdeFrom(myCustomObjectSerde.getSerializer(), myCustomObjectSerde.getDeserializer())));
        // Create KTable with custom value object
        KTable<String, MyCustomObject> kTable = textLines.
                selectKey((key, value) -> value.getElement1().concat(value.getElement2()))
          
                .toTable(Named.as("CustomKTableStore2"),Materialized.as("CustomKTableStore2").with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.serdeFrom(myCustomObjectSerde.getSerializer(), myCustomObjectSerde.getDeserializer())));

        kTable.toStream().to("custom-output-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.serdeFrom(myCustomObjectSerde.getSerializer(),myCustomObjectSerde.getDeserializer())));
    }

}
```

---

```
@RestController
public class QueryController {

    @Autowired
    StreamsBuilderFactoryBean factoryBean;

    @GetMapping(produces = "text/plain",path = "/api/get-result")
    public String getStaticQueryResult(){

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = factoryBean.getKafkaStreams();
        ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, MyCustomObject> counts = kafkaStreams.store(
                StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType("CustomKTableStore2", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore())
        );

        counts.get("1");

        return "Success";
    }

}
```

---

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.UnknownStateStoreException: Cannot get state store CustomKTableStore2 because no such store is registered in the topology.
at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.store(KafkaStreams.java:1704) ~[kafka-streams-3.5.0.jar:na]
at com.example.kafka.stream.rest.demo.controller.QueryController.getStaticQueryResult(QueryController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
```

My input to custom-input-topic looks like this json:

```
{
"element1":"1",
"element2":"2"
}
```

I can see the result of the above kstream computation in the custom-output-topic where the key is updated to 1 for the above record.

Any pointers what is wrong on why this won't work when i am trying to query the ktable directly ?